# How to replace different text on a single line from a csv?

Tags: text-processing

I know similar questions have been asked, but I am a novice, having just picked up Linux the last few months, and the particulars of my question have made me unable to adapt other solutions to my problem.

I wish to replace different strings in a single line with specific matched strings indicated in a CSV.

An example:
file1:

```
(((1[&label=1],2[&label=1])[&label=5]),3[&label=2])
```

file2.csv (two column csv):

```
1[&label, "1[&tag=2,label"
2[&label, "2[&tag=5,label"
3[&label, "3[&tag=3,label"
```

I would like to replace `1[&label` with `1[&tag=2,label` (etc...) in the single line file, such that I would end up with:

```
(((1[&tag=2,label=1],2[&tag=5,label=1])[&label=5]),3[tag=3,&label=2])
```

Note that the csv does not contain any entries for `[&label` entries without an individual tag (the `1[&label` ), but I still need those `[&label` entries in the final output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read the line to act upon
line=$(head -n 1 $1)

while read substitution
do
    # get the first field, delimited by a comma
    findvar=`echo $substitution | cut -d, -f1`
    # remove the quotes and get the second field, delimited by a space
    replacevar=`echo $substitution | sed 's/"//g' | cut -d' ' -f2`
    # replace all occurrences of the find variable with the replacement
    line=${line//$findvar/$replacevar}
done < $2

echo $line
```

If this script is named

```
substitute.sh
```

then you could call

```
sh substitute.sh file1 file2.csv
```

This is making several assumptions:

- Your CSV is in the format you describe. In your example, values in the first column are not quoted, but values in the second column are. Additionally, the example includes a space after the delimiter. You would need to adjust the script if the actual CSV format differs.
- Since substitutions from the CSV are processed one at a time, it is possible that a later substitution will match a substitution made previously. This may not be your intention.

For example, if your input line is

```
foo bar baz
```

And your CSV file with substitutions is

```
foo, "bar"
bar, "baz"
```

You might intend the result to be

```
bar baz baz
```

But the result would be

```
baz baz baz
```

Comment: Worked great and your details and comments have allowed me to make minor edits and apply the script to a variety of other find-and-replace tasks.  Thanks!